# Java Servlet concurrency clash when uploading, accessing then downloading Audio Wav files. Strange looking errors

Tags: servlets, audio, concurrency, upload

Each run of my program gives me the previous run's output instead of the current output and 3 of these errors which I can't find references to anywhere on the internet.

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started"
```

I think the issue is that the files are being processed before they have been downloaded fully. So I need find out a way to Pause the program while files are being written to their locations?

First the files are uploaded to a folder called uploads and a string of the location of another audio file to be overlaid is saved like this

```
int count = 0;
    Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();

    for (Part part : parts) {
        System.out.println("content type" + part.getContentType());
        //String fileName = extractFileName(part);
        //if the part is a bigger size than 20 i.e not just the combo box thing but an actual file

        if (part.getSize() > 20) {
            //if(part.getContentType().startsWith("audio")) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(part.getName() + " is an audio file and count is " + count);
            part.write("file" + count + ".wav");
        } else {
            System.out.println(part.getName());
        }
    }
    //get the path of the program to be overlaid
    String[] selected = request.getParameterValues("programselect");
    String program = "sound/" + selected[0];

    //create an array to hold the strings of the  and fill it
    String[] songs = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        songs[i] = "uploaded/file" + (i + 1) + ".wav";
        System.out.println("uploaded/file" + (i + 1) + ".wav");
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(songs));
```

Then these are put in a method that concatenates the string and overlays the cues.
Ideally the program would pause here until the files are uploaded to continue.

```
    try {
        //overlay program with songs
        overlay(program, songs);
        finish(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Process.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The overlay method is MEGA long so I won't include it here but the files are accessed by a method concatenate

```
public AudioInputStream concatenate(String[] songs) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In concatenate. Songs: " + Arrays.toString(songs));
    AudioInputStream concat = loadToWav("sound/noth.wav");
    System.out.println(concat.getFrameLength());
    File file = null; //changed for testing
    try {
        //for each song
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
            //load it to wav
            AudioInputStream second = loadToWav(songs[i]);

            //create a sequence input stream with the files concatenated so far and the new file
            SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(concat, second);
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " sound: " + songs[i]);
            System.out.println("concat: " + concat.getFrameLength() + " Second: " + second.getFrameLength());

            //figure out the length
            long length = concat.getFrameLength() + second.getFrameLength();
            System.out.println("length: " + length);

            //get the correct format
            AudioFormat fmt = concat.getFormat();

            //make a destination file
            file = new File("C:\\Users\\Leigh\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RUNTHIS\\src\\java\\sound\\test" + i + ".wav"); //changed for testing
            file.getParentFile().mkdir();
            file.createNewFile();

            //fill an audioinputstream with the finished sequence
            AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(sis, fmt, length);

            //write it t the file
            AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);

            concat = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

        }
        //int size = AudioSystem.write(concat, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //AudioSystem.write(concat, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, fileOut);
    //play(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
    return concat;

}
```

the finished AudioIputStream is saved to a file location

```
    AudioInputStream done = new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                isbytenew), aisc.getFormat(), aisc.getFrameLength());

        File finished = new File("C:\\Users\\Leigh\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RUNTHIS\\src\\java\\sound\\finished.wav");
        finished.getParentFile().mkdir();
        finished.createNewFile();
        AudioSystem.write(done, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, finished);
```

And then the method finish makes it a downloadable file...except it only outputs a file of length 1byte at the moment, but I want to sort out the accessing issue first.

```
public void finish(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    //http://www.go4expert.com/articles/sending-files-browser-jsp-t3094/
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("audio/x-wav");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=finished.wav");

    java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Leigh\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RUNTHIS\\src\\java\\sound\\finished.wav");
    int i;
    if (fileInputStream.getFD().valid()) {
        System.out.println("supposedly the stream is open");
    } else {
        System.out.println("supposedly the stream is closed");
    }
    while (fileInputStream.getFD().valid()) {
        try {
            while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {

                out.write(i);
                fileInputStream.close();
                out.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I know what the output is by just going to /RUNTHIS/src/java/sound/finished.wav" and listening to the file that is there and it's pretty much always wrong unless the uploaded files are very short.

The stack trace is hugely long due to my general overuse of System.out.println()'s
but here is one of the severe errors i'm getting

```
24-Apr-2014 18:59:47.670 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-12] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error processing request
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper(Mapper.java:988)
at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMap(Mapper.java:806)
at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:666)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:511)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I hope I did this right, this is my first stack overflow questions so if I've done anything heinous scold me appropriately. I'm also kind of woozy from 10 hours of straight trying to get my head round this.

Comment: `request.getParameterValues("programselect")` will not work with a multipart request. Those values are going to have to be accessed via `request.getParts()` too.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. At the point where I'm breaking other things trying to fix the broken things. Once I get that sorted it won't fix my main problem though will it?

Comment: Fixed that by adding a scanner to my parts iterator 


`if (part.getSize() > 20) {

                count++;

                part.write("file" + count + ".wav");

            } else {

                programs = part.getInputStream();

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(programs);

                program = "sound/"+scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println("the program yes? " + program);

            }

        }`